# (vscode) How to make Visual Code to show errors on a situation like JSON.Stringify?

Tags: javascript, syntax, syntax-error, visual-studio-code

Since JSON.Stringify isn't valid JS it would nice to have VScode to show error or perhaps correct automatically it into JSON.stringify.

Question is that why doesn't it do it already? And how to make it happen? I believe there could be a lot of similar cases.

Comment: You could always create a property `Stringify` on the `JSON` global. vscode doesn't know about that, but it will help you autocomplete `.stringify` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try enabling TypeScript's semantic checking in your javascript file. The easiest way to do this is by adding `// @ts-check` to the top of your js file:

```
// @ts-check

JSON.Stringify([])
```

[image]

You can also enable type checking in your entire project by setting:

```
"javascript.implicitProjectConfig.checkJs": true
```

in your VSCode settings

Here's the full documentation on ts-check: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_type-checking-and-quick-fixes-for-javascript-files